# update mysql database table fields with a single mysqli statement query

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a database table and i am updating the table columns this way.

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'db');

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo 'failed to connect to db.. <br>' . mysqli_connect_errno();
            return 'error';
        }

   $username = $data['username'];
   $data['image'] = $this->replace_whitespace($data['image']);

   foreach($data as $key=>$value){

       $this->query = "UPDATE users SET $key=? WHERE username='$username'";
       $this->statement = $mysqli->prepare($this->query);

       if($this->statement){

           $this->statement->bind_param('s', $value);
           $this->statement->execute();
           $this->statement->close();
       }

   }
```

Is it possible to update more than one table columns in one go. I tried this but in-vain.

```
   $this->query = "UPDATE users SET col1=?, col2=?, col3=? WHERE username='$username'";
   $this->statement = $mysqli->prepare($this->query);

   if($this->statement){

       $this->statement->bind_param('sss', $value1, $value2, $value3);
       $this->statement->execute();
       $this->statement->close();
   }
```

Is there a better way doing this?

```
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'db');

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo 'failed to connect to db.. <br>' . mysqli_connect_errno();
            return 'error';
        }
        $username = $data['username'];
        $this->query = "UPDATE users SET fname=?, lname=?, email=?, tpin=?, image=?, address=? country=?, city=?, state=?, postal=? WHERE username='$username'";
        $this->statement = $mysqli->prepare($this->query);

        if ($this->statement) {
            $this->statement->bind_param('ssssssssss', $data['fname'],$data['lname'],$data['email'],$data['tpin'], $data['file'], $data['address'],$data['country'],$data['city'],$data['state'], $data['post_code']);
            $this->statement->execute();
             $this->statement->close();
       }
```

This is my real code.

Comment: You have 10 parameter placeholders and 11 paramaters. The numbers need to match up!

Comment: please ignore the syntax errors in this code since its just an example to show you guys. I have been trying with same number of parameter holders and parameters. I just wanted to know the better way doing this if possible. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to update more than one table columns in one go

Yes. Actually, updating many fields in one query is a very core feature of any DBMS. You can always expect it to be supported.

> I tried this but in-vain.

Well, you have to try more, like we all do. After all, it's your job.

Two notes regarding your "real" code:

1. You have to bind ALL variables in the query, not only some of them
2. you have to configure mysqli to report errors:

   ```
   mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the "," after col3=?

This will fix the syntax error

Comment: The extra comma was just a typing mistake not in my script but over here. Actually the problem is, i need to update more then 12 columns in one go. I tried this way but it did not work. Is good practice if i use the loop and let it taking care of all updates.

Comment: No, its good practice to update all columns in one go. Can you paste your query here?

Comment: I have pasted my real code block and edited my post. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $this->query = "UPDATE users SET col1=?, col2=?, col3=?, WHERE username='$username'";
```

You have an extra comma, meaning your SQL is reading "WHERE" as another column and everything gets messed up.

```
 $this->query = "UPDATE users SET col1=?, col2=?, col3=? WHERE username='$username'";
```

Should work fine.

In response to the comment below, this is the correct way of going about it, so it must be a faulty variable somewhere, what error messages are you getting? (If any)

It could also be that one of the parameters you are binding is not a string. Regardless, we'd need a more in-depth example.

Comment: The extra comma was just a typing mistake not in my script but over here. Actually the problem is, i need to update more then 12 columns in one go. I tried this way but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it works the same way as putting new values into the database.

[Update a row mysql in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304794/update-a-row-mysql-in-php)