# How to create two update statements in one query?

Tags: php, forms, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I am making a form where you can insert, update and delete your data in database `welkom` from phpmyadmin. This is my file `Formmenu.php`. PS: This code contains Dutch language.

PHP

```
<?php
    if ( ! empty($_POST))
     {
            $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','welkom');

            if ($mysqli ->connect_error) 
            {
                die('connect error: '. $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
            }

                if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
                     $sql = "INSERT INTO abdijbieren (naam, prijs) VALUES ('{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['naam'])}','{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['prijs'])}');";

                } else if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
                    $sql = "DELETE FROM abdijbieren WHERE naam ='{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['naam'])}';";
                }
                  else if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
                    $sql = "UPDATE abdijbieren SET id='{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['id'])}' WHERE naam='{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['naam'])}'; UPDATE abdijbieren SET prijs='{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['prijs'])}' WHERE naam='{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['naam'])}';";
                }

                  else {
                      /*nothing*/
                  }



           $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);

            if ($insert)
            {
                echo "Success! Keer terug naar de volgende pagina om te updaten.";
            }else
            {
                die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
            }



            $mysqli->close();
        }

    ?>
```

Form

```
<form method="post" action="">
              <input name="naam" type="text" placeholder="naam drank" required><br>
              <input name="prijs" type="text" placeholder="prijs" required><br>
              <input name="id" type="text" placeholder="tracking number*"><br><br>

        <input type="submit" name="insert" value="insert">
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete">
        <input type="submit" name="update" value="update"><br>
        *= niet nodig bij "insert".
        </form>
```

This is what I am focusing on:

```
$sql = "UPDATE abdijbieren SET id='{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['id'])}' WHERE naam='{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['naam'])}'; UPDATE abdijbieren SET prijs='{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['prijs'])}' WHERE naam='{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['naam'])}';";
```

When I tried the code I recieved error #1064 after submitting the form. The error echoes;

> Error: 1064 : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near 'UPDATE abdijbieren SET prijs='5.00 EUR' WHERE id='9';
>   UPDATE a' at line 2

I wasn't sure if it is a typo or the real_escape_string. I tried looking for a solution with this:

- [How do I combine two UPDATE statements in one MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641970/how-do-i-combine-two-update-statements-in-one-mysql-query)
- [Update a row mysql in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304794/update-a-row-mysql-in-php)

The issue at the second link remained unsolved. I checked my code and it seemed fine, but after recieving error #1064 I am confused with the code.  I need help with this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Use `multi_query` if you have to do it in one execution, but you can also update both fields in one query..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
 $sql = "UPDATE abdijbieren SET id='{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['id'])}' , prijs='{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['prijs'])}' WHERE naam='{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['naam'])}'";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can update multiple columns in a single statement:

```
$sql = "UPDATE abdijbieren 
           SET id = '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['id']) . "',
               prijs = '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['prijs']) . "' 
         WHERE naam='" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['naam']) . "'"
```

Comment: U know its wrong to directly inject `$_POST` values in the query

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile They are not directly injected in the query. It is safe as long as `real_escape_string` method is used.. I just helped him to understand how the query must be done.. SQL injection was not part of this question..

Comment: well alryt then but u may just give few suggestions, so that he can know what he's doing aint safe

Comment: I just told you that it is safe as long as he used `$mysqli->real_escape_string()` method.. it is not safe to use the variables directly which is the case when you must use bindings

Comment: will have to disagree with u on that one

Answer (score -2):

There is no need to execute the update query for each column; you can achieve this by using a query like that:

```
'update table_name set col_1="col_1_value", col_2 ="col_2_value" where your_condition = abc';
```